# DateTime value as text, can't use filter in pivot table

Tags: excel, datetime, pivot-table

In my data source, a DateTime field I want to query is formatted as text. I am pulling this data into a pivot table in Excel and would like to be able to apply date filters on this field. Needless to say, the filter doesn't work with text values.

Is there any way to convert this to actual DateTime format within the query itself?

My current workaround is to import the data into Excel table with PowerQuery, where I can add a column that converts the text to DateTime value. But the import is extremely slow comparing to my original pivot table solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the original excel file you must create a new col where the value of cells is value of datetime col + 1.

This new col is datetime format

Comment: Not sure I follow you, I don't have "the original Excel file", my data source is an external database which I definitely cannot add that column in.